# Visual Studio 2017 - Change tooltip when hovering pointer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When debugging, VS can show a tooltip containing info of the object:

[image: int tooltip]
<sub>`int` object tooltip.</sub>

It only shows the value, because it's a basic system object;

---

When I hover the mouse over more complex object, it shows some properties:

[image: Point tooltip]
<sub>`Point` object tooltip.</sub>

Note the tooltip showing the `X` and `Y` properties of the object;

---

But when I hover over an object created by me, ...

[image: TestClass tooltip]
<sub>`TestClass` object tooltip.</sub>

... the tooltip only shows the "complete path" to the class;

---

How can I make VS show a tooltip with some properties showing (like the `System.Drawing.Point` object)?

Comment: Doesn't VS just use the type's ToString()?

Comment: See the arrow/pointy/chevrony thing on the left side? Click that, see what happens

Comment: @crunchy It shows the properties, but I wanted to make it show without clicking, only hovering

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Just tried it, worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want, for whatever reason, to avoid modifying `ToString()`'s behavior, there is an alternative.

Decorate your class with `[DebuggerDisplay(...)]`

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute

This is especially helpful when you want to change how the debugger displays information for classes that *you don't control*.  For example, we have a class `DateRange` that we want to change how the debugger displays, but we cannot modify the class itself.  Well, we can do this:

```
[assembly: DebuggerDisplay("[Start={StartDate}, End={EndDate}]", Target = typeof(DateRange))]
```

This line would go in your `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

As @SoronelHaetir commented, VS uses `ToString`.

So just overloading the `ToString` works.

**EDIT:**
This works only when hovering over the variable, not on lists.
[@Amy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348774/visual-studio-2017-change-tooltip-when-hovering-pointer/48349177#48349177) is the correct one.

Comment: I think its worth noting that there is a second way of handling this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx

Comment: @Amy can you post as an answer?  Just learned something new and want to upvote.

Comment: @Amy actually your answer is the correct, as it works even for lists. (The ToString doesnt)